# Ubuntu 16.04lts freeze on internet connection

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, freeze

My Ubuntu keeps freezing when a network connection is established. This started to happen immediately after:
Downloading and trying to install Virtualbox via deb file.
The Ubuntu software started to crash and i rebooted. Since then logging in to my account freezes the computer.
-Guest account wont work with internet.
-my account works without even when the network-adapter is connected but internet disabled.
-Ubuntu software doesn.t crash when internet is disabled.

I have 16GB ram and swap.
I ran `sudo apt-get check/autoremove/clean` without results.

Can it be a pending blocking network task that freezes the UI? How do I cancel it.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also and here is how I got it fixed...
The issue is that Ubuntun updates to the kernel version :

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic_xxx_amd64    
linux-heasers-4.4.0.63-generic_xxx_all    
linux-image-4.4.0.63-generic_xxx_amd64
```

and for some reason these versions have an issue with the wifi.( don't know what it is) 
So to fix this: here is what you will have to do: simple... revert to an older kernel version.... you ask  but how?, I have no internet connection..

So you find a usb drive and download the previous kernel versions for your ubuntu flavor and then use the usb to install the previous kernel versions.
Here is the procedure:

1. Get the ubuntu flavor for your system:

   ```
   --> `lsb_release -a`

   Codename: <ubuntu_version> ( mine is "xenial")
   ```
2. Now using another internet connected machine(library computers); go to http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and get your recent kernel files (.deb) For mine, I am using xenial Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS so I got the current kernel version.
3. Choose the folder with your ubuntu version and Download the following (.deb files)

   ```
   ---> linux-headers-xxxxx-generic-yyyyy_amd64.deb

   ---> linux-headers-xxxxx-yyyyy_all.deb

   ---> linux-image-xxxxx-generic-yyyyy_amd64.deb
   ```
4. Create a directory and put these .deb files inside e.g

   ```
   ---> `mkdir  linux_kernel_version_xxxxx`

   --->  `cp *.deb linux_kernel_version_xxxx`
   ```
5. Copy this  directory into your usb and transfer these files to your troubling ubuntu machine
6. Open  terminal (CTRL + ALT+ T or right click on desktop and choose "open Terminal" and go to the directory you just transferred from your usb drive
   and launch the package installation command as root:

   ```
   ---> `cd linux_kernel_version_xxxx`

   ---> `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`
   ```

That should install the previous kernel version and  adjust your boot appropriately so that you always boot to the kernel that does not leads to freeze once wifi adapter is connected.

If you get the error: "module_init_blah_blah", either try another previous version or find a way( using usb again?) download the "module_init_blah_blah" and install it first before trying to install the kernel or simply keep trying even more previous kernel version until you hit the right one, there are more previous kernel versions [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/):

Hope that works. Enjoy